# What is the "personality of a relationship" called?

Tags: social-psychology, personality

I'm struggling to find this missing word, that I imagine would be part of the psychological literature.

Personality is to an individual what ____________ is to a 1:1 relationship.

Any thoughts? I imagine "Culture" would be the personality equivalent for an organization, but I'm unfamiliar with similar concepts for a 1:1 relationship. Does "culture" apply equally to organizations of size 2?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Can you better describe the context for which you are asking the question?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this?

- An individual's personality
- A couple's relationship
- A group's dynamics
- An organisation's culture

Comment: This cracked me up. So the personality of a relationship is a relationship, and the entity is actually a couple. I like this...it makes sense, thank you. I guess I think we need to linguistically distinguish between "a relationship" as an entity (AKA a couple) vs. characteristics of the entity (characteristics of a couple).

Comment: Hey thanks for your comments.  Linguistically differentiating the entity from the attribute does appear to have utility. However, it highlights a difference with how we use each attribute descriptor. *Personality* encompasses both interpersonal (eg. cooperative, kind, romantic, nasty, withdrawn, sullen) and intrapersonal (eg. studious, creative, active, lazy, tired, apathetic) behaviours .  The words *relationship* and *dynamics* seem to focus exclusively on intra-couple and intra-group behaviours.  Do you agree? I would be interested if you find alternate descriptors of the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Given the blank I would suggest:

- habit

personality is an enduring pattern of relating and responding to life's challenges that has its roots in genetics and experience. Couple's relationship evolves over time and becomes similarly half-intuitive and half-conscious. But I suppose this may be a word that is not "psychological" enough.